# How to split an array of JSON documents into fixed size chunks?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have a JSON document representing an array of 100 objects and I need to process this document in batches, e.g. 10 objects per batch.

```
def text = '[{1st},{2nd},{3rd},{4th},...{100th}]'
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(text)
```

Now I need to take first 10 elements from `text` (`[{1st},{2nd},..{10th}]`) and post them into web service, then another 10 (`[{11th},{12th}...{20th}]`) and so on.

I've tried this in C# but not able to do that in Groovy.

Anyone suggest me the best way to `send batches of json` and every time total number of json has changed `dynamically`?

Comment: Does it have to be one single JSON-Object? Otherwise I would suggest sending one JSON-Object per line.

Comment: Yes it is a one single json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy adds [`Iterable.collate(int size)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.13/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#collate-java.lang.Iterable-int-) method via `DefaultGroovyMethods` class and you can use it to split your input array into n-size chunks, e.g.

```
['a','b','c','d','e'].collate(3) == [['a','b','c'], ['d','e']]
```

Consider following example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

final String text = '[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 6}]'

final List<Map> json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text) as List<Map>

json.collate(2).each { part ->
    final String out = JsonOutput.toJson(part)

    println "Sending following JSON object: ${out}"
}
```

<kbd>[Run in Groovy web console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5112506334838784)</kbd>

Here we have a JSON array of 6 objects. We parse this JSON to a `List<Map>` object and then we split into chunks of size 2 and prepare JSON for later execution. I used only 6 objects as an illustration, however it doesn't matter if the initial list contains 100 objects and we split into chunks of size 10 - the algorithm is the same.

It can be generalized and described in following steps:

1. Parse initial JSON array of objects
2. Split an array into chunks of size 10
3. Format chunk of 10 objects into JSON String
4. Process JSON document

The example shown above produces following output:

```
Sending following JSON object: [{"id":1},{"id":2}]
Sending following JSON object: [{"id":3},{"id":4}]
Sending following JSON object: [{"id":5},{"id":6}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. will check and let u know the results.

Comment: Great answer.+1